# XSLT Change Attribute Values and Sort

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I’m very new with XSLT and I’m trying to find a way to do the following…

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddCustomerRequest APIVersion="2.0" Name="Add Customers List Data">
    <CFParameters>
        <ReqId>1-YNU68</ReqId>
        <CfgId>1-TSP13</CfgId>
    </CFParameters>
    <Parameters>
        <ParName>Test Customer List</ParName>
        <ListName>Test Customer List</ListName>
        <Summary>N</Summary>
        <CustomerList>
            <CustomerInfo>
                <LoadID>1-YNU4R</LoadID>
                <CustomerID>1-E0FB</CustomerID>
                <LoadConID>1-YTQJ5</LoadConID>
                <TimeZone></TimeZone>
                <Available>Y</Available>
                <Phones>
                    <Phone PhoneType="2">6987991657</Phone>
                    <Phone PhoneType="1">6987991152</Phone>
                    <Phone PhoneType="4">6987999912</Phone>
                    <Phone PhoneType="3">6987999278</Phone>
                </Phones>
                <CustomFields></CustomFields>
            </CustomerInfo>
        </CustomerList>
    </Parameters>
</AddCustomerRequest>
```

Each Customer (CustomerInfo element) has many Phones of different PhoneType each…
PhoneType values are equivalent to the following:
                PhoneType “1” = Business 
                PhoneType “2” = Home 
                PhoneType “3” = Other
                PhoneType “4” = Mobile

The request is to sort the Phones by the following PhoneType:
1.  Mobile 
2.  Home 
3.  Business 
4.  Other

So, the final XML, should contain the Phones in the following order:

```
        <Phones>
                        <Phone PhoneType="4">6987999912</Phone>
                        <Phone PhoneType="2">6987991657</Phone>
                        <Phone PhoneType="1">6987991152</Phone>
                        <Phone PhoneType="3">6987999278</Phone>
        </Phones>
```

In order to do this, I believe I should do the following (using XSLT):
•   Replace the PhoneType values with Temp values in order to be able to sort
•   Sort the phones by PhoneType
•   Replace the temp PhoneType values with the original ones

For example:

```
            Where PhoneType = “4” to be replaced by value “101”
            Where PhoneType = “2” to be replaced by value “102”
            Where PhoneType = “1” to be replaced by value “103”
            Where PhoneType = “3” to be replaced by value “104”
```

So, Phones of the original XML would be like this:

```
<Phones>
<Phone PhoneType="102">6987991657</Phone>
<Phone PhoneType="103">6987991152</Phone>
<Phone PhoneType="101">6987999912</Phone>
<Phone PhoneType="104">6987999278</Phone>
</Phones>
```

Then, Sort the Phones by PhoneType in order to make the list like this:

```
<Phones>
<Phone PhoneType="101">6987999912</Phone>
<Phone PhoneType="102">6987991657</Phone>
<Phone PhoneType="103">6987991152</Phone>
<Phone PhoneType="104">6987999278</Phone>
</Phones>
```

And final, replace the temp PhoneType values with the original ones:

```
            Where PhoneType = “101” to be replaced by value “4”
            Where PhoneType = “102” to be replaced by value “2”
            Where PhoneType = “103” to be replaced by value “1”
            Where PhoneType = “104” to be replaced by value “3”
```

So, the final XML will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddCustomerRequest APIVersion="2.0" Name="Add Customers List Data">
    <CFParameters>
        <ReqId>1-YNU68</ReqId>
        <CfgId>1-TSP13</CfgId>
    </CFParameters>
    <Parameters>
        <ParName>Test Customer List</ParName>
        <ListName>Test Customer List</ListName>
        <Summary>N</Summary>
        <CustomerList>
            <CustomerInfo>
                <LoadID>1-YNU4R</LoadID>
                <CustomerID>1-E0FB</CustomerID>
                <LoadConID>1-YTQJ5</LoadConID>
                <TimeZone></TimeZone>
                <Available>Y</Available>
                <Phones>
                    <Phone PhoneType="4">6987999912</Phone>
                    <Phone PhoneType="2">6987991657</Phone>
                    <Phone PhoneType="1">6987991152</Phone>
                    <Phone PhoneType="3">6987999278</Phone>
                </Phones>
                <CustomFields></CustomFields>
            </CustomerInfo>
        </CustomerList>
    </Parameters>
</AddCustomerRequest>
```

I’ve tried to perform all of the above with the following XSL but although sorting is working, it does not replacing the values (so the sorting is wrong):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

        <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@Phones">
          <xsl:attribute name="PhoneType">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test=". = 1">
                <xsl:text>103</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test=". = 2">
                <xsl:text>102</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test=". = 3">
                <xsl:text>104</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test=". = 4">
                <xsl:text>101</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template match="Phones">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Phone">
                    <xsl:sort select="@PhoneType"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="@Phones">
          <xsl:attribute name="PhoneType">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test=". = 103">
                <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test=". = 102">
                <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test=". = 104">
                <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:when test=". = 101">
                <xsl:text>4</xsl:text>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could anyone assist please?

Thanks
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Phones">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Phone">
        <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before('4213', @PhoneType))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S.

```
<xsl:template match="@Phones">
```

does not match anything in your XML. And you certainly cannot have two templates matching the same set of nodes; only one of these will be applied.

In order to execute your grand plan, you would have to (1) write the `Phone` nodes into a *variable*, while replacing the `PhoneType` with another string; (2) convert that variable to a node-set; (3) sort the node-set and write it to the output, while replacing the `PhoneType` with the original value.

Comment: I appreciate your fast response! It worked just fine.
It seems simple but I would never think of this solution (just got in XSLT world),
I really thank you so much!!!